# textStim.text assignment functions different from setText() method call

Tags: python, psychopy

My reading of the docs [here](http://www.psychopy.org/api/visual/textstim.html) is that I should be able to use `mytextstim.text="test"` and `mytextstim.setText("test")`  interchangeably however I find that the direct assignment doesn't seem to be working.

e.g. in code sample below

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env python2
> #from psychopy import visual, core, data, event, gui
> from psychopy import visual, core
>
> myWin = visual.Window( allowGUI=True, fullscr=True)
>
> jstim= visual.TextStim(myWin,text="start", alignVert="center",alignHoriz="center",height=0.1)
> jstim.draw()
> myWin.flip()
> print("1: " + jstim.text)
> core.wait(2)
>
> jstim.text = "changed via direct assignment"
> jstim.draw()
> myWin.flip()
> print("2: " + jstim.text)
> core.wait(2)
>
> jstim.setText("changed via method call")
> jstim.draw()
> myWin.flip()
> print("3: " + jstim.text)
> core.wait(2)
> ```

The middle section with `jstim.text = "changed via direct assignment"`  does not get updated on the screen (although the attribute IS updated as seen from the print() statement) so I assume I've misunderstood something.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've just updated to v1.81.02 and it's resolved the problem.

i.e. the middle section DOES cause the textStim to update on screen.

I'm pretty sure I was on the immediately preceding version before.

Comment: Yes, you're right. This is a relatively new feature so upgrading should solve it for everyone. ``setText()`` is preserved for backward compatibility and because you can microcontrol logging ``setText('something', log=False)`` if you want to deviate from the ``autoLog`` attribute.